# default language metro style bug

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro

I found a bug in the metro app, when I use a diffrent default language like he-IL for RTL view (properties of the application window), I saw that the flip view simple example with 3 images is not working!!! it jumping and have bad styling, any help?
Thanks Eran.